# Moment.js not working with external javascript file

Tags: javascript, jquery, moment-timezone

The error described below is reproduced here: https://jsfiddle.net/cxhvr3Lq/

---

I am using jQuery, bootstrap, moment, and my own javascript file myjs.js. I created a minimum example where my custom javascript is not working. The code in myjs.js is:

```
function adjust_times_user_time_zone() {
    console.log(moment.tz("2015-08-05T00:00:00+01:00", "Europe/London"));
};

$(document).ready(function () {
    adjust_times_user_time_zone();
});
```

but this throws the following error, which is incomprehensible to me.

```
jquery.min.js:2 jQuery.Deferred exception: Cannot read property 'apply' of undefined TypeError: Cannot read property 'apply' of undefined
    at h.utcOffset (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment-timezone/0.5.33/moment-timezone-with-data.js:664:15)
    at Function.moment.updateOffset (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment-timezone/0.5.33/moment-timezone-with-data.js:623:9)
    at h.fn.tz (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment-timezone/0.5.33/moment-timezone-with-data.js:638:12)
    at Function.tz (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment-timezone/0.5.33/moment-timezone-with-data.js:568:7)
    at adjust_times_user_time_zone (file:///Users/js/myjs.js:37:24)
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (file:///Users/js/myjs.js:41:5)
    at e (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js:2:30005)
    at t (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js:2:30307) undefined

jquery.min.js:2 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'apply' of undefined
    at h.utcOffset (moment-timezone-with-data.js:664)
    at Function.moment.updateOffset (moment-timezone-with-data.js:623)
    at h.fn.tz (moment-timezone-with-data.js:638)
    at Function.tz (moment-timezone-with-data.js:568)
    at adjust_times_user_time_zone (myjs.js:37)
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (myjs.js:41)
    at e (jquery.min.js:2)
    at t (jquery.min.js:2)
```

I am loading jquery, bootstrap, moment, and myjs in that sequence. Any idea what is wrong?

Comment: I could not reproduce the problem. See [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3ponu4wj/5/).

Comment: Thanks for looking into this and suggesting JSFiddle. I am able to replicate this error. https://jsfiddle.net/cxhvr3Lq/

Comment: The way you have that fiddle configured is broken. You're including several of the libraries twice, once in the fiddle configs and again in the html section. Once that's fixed, it works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

moment's version needs to be at least 2.9.0. From the docs :

```
To use moment-timezone, you will need moment@2.9.0+, moment-timezone.js, and the moment-timezone data.
```

https://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/

Here is a working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/75oLy36p/